# SQLCipher library for an own library (need something to do with "assets" folder)

Tags: android

I need encryption for the SQLite database in my library project. I tried SQLCipher and it is a nice library, but it has a big lack when used in a library project - the icudt46l.zip file, which has to be put in the assets folder. The problem is that it can't be put to the assets folder of my library, but has to be put to the assets folder of my customers' applications. It's very inconvenient. Can you, please, suggest another SQLite encryption library or a workaround with SQLCipher?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own library.

Write a method which takes inputs and returns encrypted outputs, then you can write those outputs to SQLite.

Similarly you have to write decrption method(with using the same key) then you can read your encrypted datas from db.

Turn this project to library or use these methods directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to use the "assets" folder of a library in an application. I use IntelliJ and in the `.iml` file of an application the following line must be added:

```
<includeAssetsFromLibraries>true</includeAssetsFromLibraries>
```

I haven't check the other IDEs yet, but I think, that there must be something for other IDEs too.